# selecting specific rows based on NA pattern

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I want to remove specific observations that occur before two conditions are met. I want to remove observations where B = 1 and A = 1 IF it occurs before A = 1 AND B = 1. I have data that look like this.

```
PID    Time     A        B
1        2      NA       1     
1        3      1        NA
1        4      1        1
2        1      NA       1       
2        2      1        1 
2        3      1        NA
```

I want this, where cases that have A = 1 or B = 1 are removed IF they occur before cases where A = 1 AND B = 1. I also want cases where A = NA or B = NA that occur after A = 1 AND B = 1.

```
PID    Time     A        B
1        4      1        1
2        1      NA       1       
2        2      1        1 
2        3      1        NA
```

I tried using ifelse to do this and couldn't get it to work. Can anyone advise to make this work?

Comment: is the PID influencing the selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an idea.
Create a new column indicating if the condition A = 1 and B = 1 is matched. Sum all matched events and filter all rows before the first match.

```
df %>%
  mutate(f = ifelse(df$A == 1 & df$B == 1 &
                      !is.na(df$A) & !is.na(df$B), 1, 0)) %>%
  group_by(PID) %>%
  mutate(f = cumsum(f)) %>%
  filter(f > 0) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-f)


# A tibble: 2 x 4
    PID  Time     A     B
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     4     1     1
2     2     2     1     1
```

Comment: Thank you @tamtam!

Comment: I realized I needed something a little different. Do you know how I could modify your code to accommodate what I want?

Comment: For your desired output it seems PID is not as important as we all thought. So to get the output from above you can remove `group_by(PID)` from the code. Therefore just the rows before the  first A = 1 and B = 1 in the dataset will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `fill` to replace the NA elements with non-NA adjacent values in 'A', 'B' and `filter` with `duplicated`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(PID) %>%
   fill(c(A, B), .direction = 'updown') %>% 
   filter(!duplicated(cbind(A, B), fromLast = TRUE))
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   PID [2]
#    PID  Time     A     B
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     4     1     1
#2     2     2     1     1
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun!

Comment: @D.Fowler if it works, please consider to accept solution. thanks